# How to detect that my appid is already running on a given chromecast device?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I would like my app to notice if a chromecast device is already running my app id when I open it but I'm a little unsure as to how to do it, I thought maybe the MediaRouteAdapter.onDeviceAvailable event would do it but it doesn't seem to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you establish a session to the device to receive the ApplicationMetadata in its callback and see if that is your app or not?

Comment: Yeah, I can probably do something like that, I was just hoping there was a more obvious way of doing it. In the guide which was released today it shows as if it is possible to see what apps are running on each device so it can be shown on the menu, https://developers.google.com/cast/design_consider#sender-cast-menu-available